# What is the difference between IAAS and web hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting, cloud

I've been googling to find out exactly what IAAS (Infrastructure As A Service) is, but I don't understand how it is different from web hosting?

Answer (score 2):

Definition of [Infrastructure as a Service](http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/definition/Infrastructure-as-a-Service-IaaS)

> Infrastructure as a Service is a provision model in which an
>   organization outsources the equipment used to support operations,
>   including storage, hardware, servers and networking components. The
>   service provider owns the equipment and is responsible for housing,
>   running and maintaining it. The client typically pays on a per-use
>   basis.
>
> Characteristics and components of IaaS include:
>
> -Utility computing service and billing model.
>   -Automation of administrative tasks.
>   -Dynamic scaling.
>   -Desktop virtualization.
>   -Policy-based services.
>   -Internet connectivity.

Definition of [web hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service)

> A web hosting service is a type of Internet hosting service that allows individuals and organizations to make their website accessible via the World Wide Web. Web hosts are companies that provide space on a server owned or leased for use by clients, as well as providing Internet connectivity, typically in a data center.

As you can see IaaS offers more functionality and flexibility then web hosting. But at a cost.

Answer (score 0):

No difference really other than Flexibility.

Iaas :

The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing,” in IaaS, “the capability provided to the consumer is to provision processing, storage, networks, and other fundamental computing resources where the consumer is able to deploy and run arbitrary software,
which can include OSs and applications. The consumer does not manage or control the
underlying cloud infrastructure but has control over OSs, storage, and deployed applications; and possibly limited control of select networking components

Hosting Fits the same definition As Iaas.. like Iaas there are different products that allow for more (resource ,controls, etc..) at a cost.  your site could be server side scripted .. in a sense it is an application . that then runs on Hosted servers. Web , App, DB etc.